# comparing two value within a table and using trigger to update another column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like below

```
id  id_dosen id_dosen2 tetangga1 tetangga2
1   1        2         null      null      
2   2        3         null      null      
3   1        3         null      null  
4   4        5         null      null
5   4        6         null      null
6   6        null      null      null
```

i need to compare row 1's id_dosen and id_dosen2 with the one on all other row and do the same from row 2 and so on, given the example i need to know if row 1 had any same value with other row, if there is then **trigger an update** to tetangga1 and tetangga 2 where the value in tetangga1 and tetangga2 will be the id of the row which has the same value with the current row, so the table will be like this

```
id  id_dosen id_dosen2 tetangga1 tetangga2
1   1        2         2         3                
2   2        3         1         3      
3   1        3         1         2
4   4        5         5         null         
5   4        6         4         6
6   6        null      5         null
```

explanation: row 1 will have row 2's id in its tetangga1 column because row 1's id_dosen2 had the same value with row 2's id_dosen. 
row 1 will have row 3's id in its tetangga2 column because row 1's id_dosen had the same value with row 3's id_dosen

can anyone help me?

Comment: I can't really understand your logic for assigning tetangga1 and 2. Can you be more specific? What if e.g. there is a row with id=4 which matches too? How do you select?

Comment: there's a condition which doesnt allow for an id_dosen to appear more than twice. 

so if there's a 4th row , it wont contain any id_dosen or id_dosen2 that already appeared twice. thats why there's only two tetangga

Comment: i updated the table with more rows to expand the example

Comment: Shouldn't id 5 have tetangga2 = 6?

Comment: yes i updated it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not an easy problem to solve in MySQL, but it is doable. This query ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/29024d/1)) works on your sample data:

```
UPDATE table1, (SELECT id, tetangga1, IF(tetangga2 = tetangga1, NULL, tetangga2) AS tetangga2
FROM (SELECT t1.id AS id, MIN(t2.id) AS tetangga1, MAX(t2.id) AS tetangga2
      FROM table1 t1
      JOIN table1 t2
      ON (t2.id_dosen  = t1.id_dosen OR t2.id_dosen  = t1.id_dosen2 OR
          t2.id_dosen2 = t1.id_dosen OR t2.id_dosen2 = t1.id_dosen2) AND
          t2.id != t1.id
      GROUP BY t1.id) t3) t4
SET table1.tetangga1 = t4.tetangga1, table1.tetangga2 = t4.tetangga2
WHERE table1.id = t4.id
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help! im gonna try to apply it to my database

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but try this:

```
MERGE
INTO    mytable t1
USING   mytable t2
ON      (
        t1.id_dosen2 = t2.id
        )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET    tetangga1 = t2.id_dosen, tetangga2 = t2.id_dosen2
```

Comment: MYSQL doesn't support the `MERGE` statement

Comment: so any other way to get the result?